# How to use Hashlib to MD5 hash a number?

Tags: python, md5, hashlib

It seems everyone is doing this:

```
import hashlib 

# initializing string 
str = "GeeksforGeeks"

# encoding GeeksforGeeks using encode() 
# then sending to md5() 
result = hashlib.md5(str.encode())
```

However, I want to hash plain numbers. Something like

```
result = hashlib.md5(0) 
#or
var = 5
result = hashlib.md5(var)
```

isn't working, and I've tried lots of other variations. What's the right syntax?

Comment: Isn't working how? What errors are you getting?

Comment: str(num).encode()?

Answer (score 2):

Hashes operate on a sequence of *bytes*.

An integer in Python is just simply a logical value; it has no definite size or byte-wise representation. If you want to hash numbers, you need to decide what form to put the number in before hashing it.

The simplest option would be to hash the *string representation* of the number. Do this by calling `str` and hashing that result. E.g.

```
var = 5
hash_input = str(var)
result = hashlib.md5(hash_input)
```

Another option would be to choose a fixed size, and hash the binary representation of the number:

```
var = 5
hash_input = struct.pack('<I', var)  # Little-endian 32-bit unsigned
result = hashlib.md5(hash_input)
```

The correct way to do this totally depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, which you haven't told us.

Comment: I'm trying to hash the specific value. For example, I want 5 to be the byte value of 5 (0101)

Comment: What if you provide a number latger than 255, or less than zero?

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Comment: Let's say you want to hash `5`. That means you could hash the bytes: `05`, or `05 00` (uint16 LE), or `05 00 00 00` (uint32 LE), or `00 05` (uint16 BE), or `00 00 00 05` (uint32 BE). You need to  **decide** the binary format of the data you want to hash. So tell me, if you wanted to hash the value 123456, what would be the string of bytes you'd feed to the hash?

Comment: I want to try all of them in order to find something that hashes what I want (brute force reverse search). How can I specify 00, 00 00, 00 00 00, 01.... etc?

Answer (score 1):

Hashing plain numbers is ambiguous, to say the least.
The number should be converted to bytes before being fed to the digest algorithm. The first problem that you'll run into is how much byte size the number occupies, could be 4 byte, 8 byte or whatever. Then comes endianness, the order of bytes in memory. All these would result in different digest for seemingly the same number. (For simplicity, I've assumed the number is int)

```py
>>> hashlib.md5(b'4').hexdigest()
'a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c'
>>> i = 4
>>> hashlib.md5(i.to_bytes(2, 'big')).hexdigest()
'c244b9cdf7853b5693a295e384c07367'
>>> hashlib.md5(i.to_bytes(4, 'big')).hexdigest()
'ea4959eb64a1f09be580d950964f3843'
>>> hashlib.md5(i.to_bytes(8, 'big')).hexdigest()
'59cff542fae7e0c4267e45740a12c9a0'
```

So, your solution would be to convert the `int` to `str` and encode it so you can get a digest from it.

```
# either this
>>> hashlib.md5(b'4').hexdigest()
# or
>>> hashlib.md5(str(4).encode()).hexdigest()
```

Hope that helps.